# Is there a way I can update Salesforce Production directly without Sandbox?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I have deployed all triggers and classes to Salesforce Sandbox instances. The triggers have passsed the 75% requirement and now I have created a Change Set in SandBox and deployed to Production.

But if I have a trigger lets say "CreateAccount (after insert)" now in Production and I make a change to the trigger , does that mean I need to redeploy to SandBox , create a change set and re deploy to Production ? or can i deploy straight to Production ? (issue may be that the tests need to be re-run before deployment to Production).

Or can i deploy to SandBox and instead of creating a Change set in Salesforce, maybe programatically create one in c# that deploys to Production after tests are run ,that way I will know all my triggers and classes ?

Whats the best / typical way to maintain data in Production ?

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce does not allows changing apex classes and triggers in production directly using the UI or developer console. These changes have to be made outside of Salesforce production environments like in a sandbox or an IDE manually and then deployed to production.

You can create and update declative changes like fields, objects, workflows, process builder, Vf pages,  Aura components directly in production using the native interface. You can also deploy all your changes to apex classes, pages and other components directly to production using IDE or a deployment tool, however this is not considered as a best practice .

Changing your live environment directly means the users may start facing issues if something goes wrong, Alao if you have multiple people working with you they maybe working on the code which is not same as production and that increases risks to your business. So a best practice is usually to have atleast one or more sandboxes where changes are done, properly tested and then moved to production.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make certain configuration changes to directly to production but you can not make code changes directly to production.
2. Best practices is to
   a. ALWAYS make changes(configuration or code) to sandbox
   b. Test changes, and run test classes
   c. Move changes to production

You might feel confident about making configuration changes directly to production, DON'T do it for following reasons

1. You never know what business processes are affected because of harmless looking configuration changes. For example, creating field update via workflow or process builders might affect another workflow rule for which that specific field was input parameter.
2. In long run, you will have a sandbox which is significantly out of sync with production

The only thing which I create directly in production are

1. Email Templates
2. Reports and Dashboards