# Developer Access to PROD environment

Tags: administration, developer-org

I am a junior salesforce admin. I am working for a small firm and I am the only Salesforce person in the company.
Can anyone help me on how I can setup Dev access in PROD so if I need to make any changes directly in PROD, I can. Not that I would as best practice I will still be developing in Sandbox.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not apply tags which have nothing to do with your question. The `[community]` tag is for the `Salesforce Communities` feature and `[salesforce-dx]` tag is, obviously, for the `Salesforce DX` feature.

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321395/is-there-a-way-i-can-update-salesforce-production-directly-without-sandbox answer your question

Comment: @Swetha Please use the "duplicate" close feature to suggest duplicates.

Comment: Sure. Will do it going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only user, then surely you are already the System Administrator, correct? You can *deploy* your changes to production, but you can **cannot** edit code (e.g. Apex) directly in production. Code requires unit tests to run, so you can't just make a quick edit without running all the tests. This is why you must use a Sandbox or an external tool (e.g. Salesforce DX) to modify code in production, and even so, for rapid development, you'll want to use a Sandbox or Scratch Org so you don't have to wait minutes for the tests to run every time you change a line of code.