# Can we manually clone the process builder in production?

Tags: process-builder, deployment

Can we manually clone the process builder and update it in production after testing in sandbox instead of deploying?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do directly in Production. But the recommended/safest/best approach is to do first in Sandbox, then test and then deploy in production

Changing your live environment directly means the users may start facing issues if something goes wrong, Alao if you have multiple people working with you they maybe working on the code which is not same as production and that increases risks to your business. So a best practice is usually to have atleast one or more sandboxes where changes are done, properly tested and then moved to production.

For more guidance, refer this [Best practice for deploying](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321395/is-there-a-way-i-can-update-salesforce-production-directly-without-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

"Deploying" is the simply the automation of making manual changes. The end result is the same: the system has been modified in some way. However, doing it manually carries some risk: you must repeat the same changes *exactly* or you could end up with logic bugs. I would recommend that you do not directly make changes in production, but instead use an appropriate deployment tool. This minimizes the risk that you'll make a mistake while making the modification again.